# Plotting columns of DataFrame as scatterplots against same y-column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a DataFrame `df` representing the CSV data found in [Advertising.csv](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv).

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('Advertising.csv', index_col=0)
>>> df.head(5)

      TV  Radio  Newspaper  Sales
1  230.1   37.8       69.2   22.1
2   44.5   39.3       45.1   10.4
3   17.2   45.9       69.3    9.3
4  151.5   41.3       58.5   18.5
5  180.8   10.8       58.4   12.9
```

I would like to plot each column in my DataFrame against the Sales column in their own respective scatterplot, i.e.
[image]

I managed to do so with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

f, ax_l = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(14, 4))

for e, col_name in enumerate(df.loc[:, :'Newspaper'].columns):
    ax_l[e].scatter(df[col_name], df.Sales, alpha=0.5, color='r')
    ax_l[e].set_xlabel(col_name)
    ax_l[e].set_ylabel('Sales')
```

**My question is**, is there a construct within `df.plot` which could make this task easier that going into Matplotlib and looping as I did?

---

*Motivation*

I know in R, to achieve a similar result I would do something like

```
savePar <- par(mfrow=c(1,3))
col     <- adjustcolor( 'red', 0.5 )
with( Advertising,
      { plot( TV       , Sales, pch=19, col=col )
        plot( Radio    , Sales, pch=19, col=col )
        plot( Newspaper, Sales, pch=19, col=col )
      }
    )
```

which admittedly seems quite a bit cleaner than my Pandas approach IMO, and got me questioning whether there is a more straightforward way to plot columns of DataFrames in this manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do it fully within the `df.plot()` method, but there is a much simpler way to draw your graphs:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(14,4))

for xcol, ax in zip(['TV', 'Radio', 'Newspaper'], axes):
    df.plot(kind='scatter', x=xcol, y='Sales', ax=ax, alpha=0.5, color='r')
```

The approach here is to use the built-in `zip` function to pair column names with individual `axis` objects. You can pass the `axis` object directly to `df.plot` to tell it which `axis` to use. You can also specify the column names of the x and y data columns in the call to `df.plot()`.

With the data subset you provided, this produces:

[image: Three graphs]

Comment: Ahh using `df.plot` for the things it inherently gives you. Thanks!